# MsgBox displaying old icons. How do I fix this?

Tags: vbscript, icons, msgbox

So I have minimal experience in VBScript. I only need it for a little project I'm doing and I just need a bit of assistance because I can't find this anywhere else. When it creates a MsgBox, the error icons are the ones from Windows 7. Although this doesn't matter that much to me it would be nice of someone knew how to fix this.

[image: Picture of Windows 10 error icon vs. What it gives me]

Answer (score 1):

That is the icon in user32.dll. VBS `Msgbox` is a wrapper around the system's `MessageBox()` function in that dll.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox

The icon you want is from ComCtl32.dll.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference